# Problema de Parse Error no PHP

Tags: php

Está dando erro na linha 62

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

```html
<div id="navtoplist">
<?


// Si estan definidas las variables de las cookies se procede a mostrar el menu pero no sin antes comprobar que los
// datos de las cookies verdaderamete son del usuario en cuestion.

if(isset($_COOKIE["usNick"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usPass"]))
{

// Se incluyen los archivos necesarios




// Se sanitizan los datos de las cokies

$user=uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);

// Se selecciona la tabla tb_users donde el usuario es el que se provee en la cookie
require('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
mysql_close($con);
// Se sanitiza de nuevo la cookie

$wask = uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);

// Se define $wesk como el nombre de usuario de la tabla tb_users

$wesk = $row['username'];

// Se comprueba que el dato de la cookie sea el mismo que el de la tabla, de lo contrario se muestra error, se termina
// el script y se borra la cookie.

if("$wesk" != "$wask") {
echo "Login incorreto.";
?>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
<?
exit();
}

// Se sanitiza la cookie usPass

$wazk = uc($_COOKIE["usPass"]);

// Se define $wezk como el nombre de usuario de la tabla tb_users

$wezk = $row['password'];

// Se comprueba que el dato de la cookie sea el mismo que el de la tabla, de lo contrario se muestra error, se termina
// el script y se borra la cookie.

if("$wezk" != "$wazk") {
echo "Login incorreto.";
?>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">

</div>
```

Não tem nada na linha 62.

Comment: Onde fecha esse `if("$wezk" != "$wazk") {`? Tenta identar o código para ser mais fácil de ler...

Comment: Vlw, só que deu outro erro: The Field is not Valid

Comment: O problema pode estar dentro do arquivo `config.php`

Comment: procure resolver um problema por vez. se resolveu a dúvida principal, marque como resolvido e caso tenha outra questão, mesmo que oriunda ou relacionada com script que postou, abre nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Analizando o código da para observar que tinha dois if's sem fechar. Caso tenha mais códigos adiante, procure postar a pagina completa para maior compreendimento de todos

```
<div id = "navtoplist" >
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE["usNick"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usPass"])) {
    $user = uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);

    require('config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username='$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_close($con);

    $wask = uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);
    $wesk = $row['username'];

    if ($wesk != $wask) {
        echo 'Login incorreto.';
        echo '< input type = "button" value = "Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()" >';
        exit();
    }

    $wazk = uc($_COOKIE["usPass"]);
    $wezk = $row['password'];

    if ($wezk != $wazk) {
      echo 'Login incorreto.';
      echo '<input type = "button" value = "Reload Page" onClick = "window.location.reload()">';
    }
}
?>
</div>
```